# Accepting socket connections only from given network interface

Tags: sockets

I'm using the Berkeley socket API in C. Is there a way to specify network interface when creating/binding/listening the socket? For example if the server is connected to internet with ethernet cable and also connected to private wifi or VPN, I want it only to accept connections from the private network.